# Make one div min-height equal another div-height plus px

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make the min-height of ecHeight equal the height of custHeightFix plus a number of pixels. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I'm new at this!

```
var elmnt = document.getElementById("custHeightFix");
var idmHeight = elmnt.offsetHeight; 
document.getElementById("ecHeight").style.minHeight = idmHeight +"5000";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your code:

1. `idmHeight` is number; you have to add number (`5000`) with it not string (`"5000"`) to perform the arithmetic operation. If you add string version of number, string concatenation will happen.
   i,e: `18 + "5000"` will result `"185000"`.
2. You also have to specify the unit like `px` at the end.

Try `idmHeight + 5000 + "px"`

```js
var elmnt = document.getElementById("custHeightFix");
var idmHeight = elmnt.offsetHeight;
var el = document.getElementById("ecHeight");
el.style.minHeight = idmHeight + 5000 + "px";
el.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
console.log(el.style.minHeight);
```

```html
<div id="custHeightFix">custHeightFix</div>
<div id="ecHeight">ecHeight</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Also, I addeed the code to the footer instead of the head.